# Validation Rule error

Tags: validation-rule, roll-up-summary

I'm having an issue with the following Validation rule, the issue only arose yesterday for the first time. The rule is as follows:

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Sync_to_Sage__c, 'Ready to Sync'), 
    Total_Amount__c != Labour_Net_Amount__c + Parts_Net_Amount__c 
)
```

The issue is that the validation rule is being set off even though the total amount is equal to the labour + Parts amount

I've queried the results of total amount, Labour net amount and Parts net amount in the Dev Console and the three results are adding up correctly. All three fields are Roll up summary fields.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what may be causing this?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The issue is that the validation rule is being set off even though the total amount is equal to the labour + Parts amount

Comment: If `Total_Amount__c`, `Labour_Net_Amount__c`, and `Parts_Net_Amount__c` are all rollup summary fields, (with `Total_Amount__c` presumably being the sum of the other two) why do you need a validation rule at all? A case could be made to verify that the rollups behave correctly via a unit test, but having a validation rule to verify that a calculation that isn't performed by a human turned out correctly seems rather pointless to me.

Comment: My previous comment aside, when you query the values of `Labour_Net_Amount__c ` and `Parts_Net_Amount__c`, how many decimal places is Salesforce showing? It's entirely possible that at least one of these fields on at least one of the child records has a deviation of an incredibly small fraction of your currency, or some other rounding error that only appears when storing values from other calculations (as opposed to directly using the results of those other calculations).

Comment: They are rolling up from the same object, the child object is marked as either parts (Which adds into Parts total), labour (Which adds into Labour total) or other which should have no value against it. The validation is to ensure that a value is not entered on lines marked as other. The queried results don't actually have any decimal places. This had been working fine for months but has stopped working since yesterday, nothing had changed on the object in a few weeks.

Comment: Sounds like your validation rule belongs on the child object instead of the parent object. Preventing people from entering a value on 'Other' records in the first place is better (as opposed to allowing them to do it at first, and then detecting and complaining about it, and forcing your users to fix their mistakes all at once). Beyond that, I think you'll need to execute some anonymous apex (basically, re-create your rollups, but in Apex, and debug the output) to get any more information about what's going wrong.